# Generate a table in Excel where there some output occurs x times

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to recreate codenames in Excel and the last thing I am missing is to create a "map" of the names, which looks like this.

[image: this]

Basically it is a table where 9/8 spots are blue, 8/9 spots are red, one is black and the rest are white.

Answer (score 1):

To do this with formulas, it will take the Dynamic Array formulas available in Office 365 Subscription:

```
=CHOOSE(INDEX(UNIQUE(RANDARRAY(100000,,1,25,TRUE)),SEQUENCE(5,,0)*5+SEQUENCE(1,5)),"B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","R","R","R","R","R","R","R","R",CHOOSE(RANDBETWEEN(1,2),"B","R"),"Bl","W","W","W","W","W","W","W")
```

`UNIQUE(RANDARRAY(100000,,1,25,TRUE))` builds an array of the numbers between 1 and 25 in a random pattern.

`INDEX(...,SEQUENCE(5,,0)*5+SEQUENCE(1,5))` builds those into a 5 by 5 array.

Then the CHOOSE will place the correct color as words in the correct cell, with `CHOOSE(RANDBETWEEN(1,2),"Blue","Red")` randomly choosing whether the "extra" is black or red.

---

To do it with normal formula, one will need a helper column

```
=AGGREGATE(14,7,ROW($1:$25)/(COUNTIFS($Z$1:Z1,ROW($1:$25))=0),RANDBETWEEN(1,25-COUNT($Z$1:Z1)))
```

And copy down 25 rows.

[image]

then put this in A1 and copy over 5 and down 5:

```
=CHOOSE(INDEX($Z$2:$Z$26,(ROW(A1)-1)*5+COLUMN(A1)),"B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","R","R","R","R","R","R","R","R",CHOOSE(RANDBETWEEN(1,2),"B","R"),"Bl","W","W","W","W","W","W","W")
```

---

Then it is just a matter of creating conditional formatting rules to turn the words into the colors.

then hit F9 to make another random design to create the random numbers between 1 and 25.  In Z1 put `Helper` then in Z2 put:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Although I have to ask, is there no way to do it outside office 365? Because my office 365 has my local language funcions (which is honestly so stupid) and I don't know how to change it (sorry, I never use office 365 otherwise)

Comment: You can use VBA, to do it.  But with formula, it would not be as easy with non Dynamic Array formula.

Comment: Would it not be somehow possible to just create a random sequence of 25 words of which 8 would be B, 9 R, 7W and 1 black? To make a table out of that should not so difficult then?

Comment: It would need to have helper columns.

Comment: Ah I see! Well, it is ugly now, but hey, it works, so thats good enough for me! All the macros I did there are also awful, since last I worked with excel macros, I was on highschool and those were like 2 lessons. Anyway, thanks for the effort anyway, I appreciate it!

Comment: @JirkaČep I have added formula that will work in 2010 and later.

Comment: @ScottCraner,, it's really a nice idea drawing checker board,, +1 ☺